# CSS only works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need to hand in this website tonight, but it only works in Chrome. I've tried everything I can think of (I'm very new to this, only learned about HTML and CSS a couple of weeks ago). The HTML seems to work fine, but my stylesheet doesn't seem to work.

**The CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */
body {
    background-image: url('http://oi43.tinypic.com/2yvmjvq.jpg');
    color: #FFF;
}

::selection {
    background: #FB5549;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #FB5549;
}

a.class2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1B21;
}

a.class2:visited {
    color: #1F1B21;
}

a.class2:hover {
    color: #1F1B21;
}

a.class2:active {
    color: #1F1B21;
}

a.class1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a.class1:visited {
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

a.class1:hover {
    color: #FB5549;
    font-style: italic;
}

a.class1:active {
    color: #FB5549;
}

a.class3 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

a.class3:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

a.class3:hover {
    color: #FB5549;
    font-style: bold;
}

a.class3:active {
    color: #FB5549;
}

a.class4 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

a.class4:visited {
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

a.class4:hover {
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

a.class4:active {
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

#wrapper {
    clear: both;
    width: 690px;
    margin-top: 85px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -8.0em;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "lobster 1.4";
    color: #1F1B21;
    font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "aleo";
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

h6 {
    font-family: "lekton";
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 208px;
    top: 145.5px;
    width: 8em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
    font-family: "consolas";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: right;
}

aside {
    position: fixed;
    left: 1046px;
    top: 145.5px;
    width: 177px;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
    font-family: "consolas";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: justify;
}

#content {
    width: 650px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "lekton";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #C6C6C6;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 690px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <br>
      <title>Start</title>
      <link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css>
         <style type="text/css">
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav>
         <h2><a href="index.html" class="class4" title="Tilbage til startsiden">menu</a></h2>
         <a href="start.html" class="class1">start</a><br>
         <a href="om mig.html" class="class1">om mig</a><br>
         <a href="skolearbejde.html" class="class1">skolearbejde</a><br>
         <a href="http://www.rtgkom.dk/wiki/Main_Page" class="class1" target="blank">rtgkom</a><br>
      </nav>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <header>
            <h1><a href="start.html" class="class2">laura Andersen</a></h1>
         </header>
         <div id="content">
            <article>
               <hgroup>
                  <h2>om siden</h2>
               </hgroup>
               <p>
                  Dette er mit studieweb på <a href="http://www.rtgkom.dk/wiki/Main_Page" class="class3" target="blank">rtgkom</a>, hvor jeg lægger alle de relevante projekter ud, som jeg arbejder på i sammenhæng med mit gymnasieforløb. Siden er lavet i faget kommunikation/it, hvor vi har arbejdet med HTML og CSS.
               </p>
            </article>
         </div>
         <footer>
            <center>
               <h6>Lavet af <a href="index.html" class="class3">Laura Andersen</a><br>
                  Sidst opdateret den 22. oktober 2013
               </h6>
            </center>
         </footer>
      </div>
      <aside>
         <h2>hvad laver jeg?</h2>
         <p>Jeg er i gang med at lave mit studieweb. Vi er startet på emnet "grafisk design".</p>
      </aside>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. *What* exactly doesn't work and *how* should it work?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not some personal-gold-support forum.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but when I look at the website in other browsers than Chrome, it looks like I don't have a stylesheet at all. Like it's only the HTML that shows on the site, and that the CSS has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Shadow Wizard: I'm aware of that, but I've tried asking some of my classmates, and they have no idea what's wrong either. You see, a couple of them have the same problem. We somply want to solve a problem, and I saw no other solution than to ask online.

Comment: I've removed 'urgent' from the question. Questions that are clear and well-formed are more likely to be answered fast. If you want a fast answer, it is up to you to create a clear question. You can do this for example by following [the checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Can you show us with screenshots what is happening?

Comment: Multiple points of improvement though. **`1.`** Do not use `center`-tags. Use `margin: auto;` instead. **`2.`** Do not use `hgroup` when you only have one heading inside it. **`3.`** Put your navigation items in an unorderd list. **`4.`** At least specify the font species (serif, sans-serif) And don't use so many different fonts. *And so on.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing '"' in the link tag:

```
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css>
```

change it to `<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: Thanks. Our teacher gave os a "template" we could use, and apparently he forgot a ". We're all correcting it now. Thanks, you're a life-saver.

Comment: @user2925281 Wow, looks like your teacher might need a few lessons himself :(

Answer (score 0):

Try running all your HTML through a validator, such as [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/), to check for errors.